The volume of the unit ball in $L((\mathbb{R}^n, \| \cdot \|_2), (\mathbb{R}^m, \| \cdot \|_2))$ with the operator norm
Consider the normed space $(X_{n, m}, \| \cdot \|) = L((\mathbb{R}^n, \| \cdot \|_2), (\mathbb{R}^m, \| \cdot \|_2))$ of linear operators $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ endowed with the operator norm. Let $B_{n, m} = \{L \in X_{n, m} \mid \|L\| \leq 1\} \subseteq X$ be the unit ball in this space. What is the volume $V_{n, m} = \operatorname{vol}(B_{n, m})$ of $B_{n, m}$ viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n m}$?
Note that since $\|A\| = \|A^T\|$, we have $V_{n, m} = V_{m, n}$.
I have tried to compute this number numerically and have obtained the following results for $\tilde{V}_{n, m} = \frac{1}{2^{n m}} V_{n, m}$:



$\tilde{V}_{n, m}$
$n = 1$
$n = 2$
$n = 3$




$m = 1$
$1$
$0.783764$
$0.507376$


$m = 2$
$0.783764$
$0.357734$
$0.082608$


$m = 3$
$0.507376$
$0.082608$
$0.006470$



Here is the code that generated these numbers:
import numpy as np
import copy

def cartesian_product(dict_of_lists):
    l = [dict()]
    keys = list(dict_of_lists.keys())
    for key in keys:
        new_l = []
        for d in l:
            for e in dict_of_lists[key]:
                new_d = copy.deepcopy(d)
                new_d[key] = e
                new_l.append(new_d)
        l = new_l
    list_of_dicts = l
    return list_of_dicts

def matrix(n, m, mat):
    res = np.zeros((n, m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            res[i, j] = mat[(i, j)]
    return res

def volume(n, m, k):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            d[(i, j)] = list(np.linspace(-1, 1, k + 1))
    l = cartesian_product(d)
    count_total = 0
    count_in_ball = 0
    for mat in l:
        norm = np.linalg.norm(matrix(n, m, mat), ord=2)
        count_total += 1
        if norm <= 1:
            count_in_ball += 1
    return (count_in_ball / count_total) # * 2**(n*m)

goal = 10**6
for n in range(1, 3 + 1):
    for m in range(1, 3 + 1):
        k = np.ceil(goal**(1/(n*m)) - 1).astype("int")
        print(n, m, k, (k + 1)**(n*m), volume(n, m, k))


This should give you the numbers on the diagonal of your table, right?

@tjah Yes, thanks. In particular, we have $\tilde{V}{2, 2} = \frac{1}{2^{2 \cdot 2}} \frac{2}{3} \pi^2 \approx 0.411233$, which is at least somewhat close to the value that I calculated numerically. We also have $\tilde{V}{3, 3} = \frac{1}{2^{3 \cdot 3}} \frac{8}{45} \pi^4 \approx 0.033822$ which is quite a lot larger than what I calculated.

For $n=1$, $B_{n,m}$ is simply the unit ball in $R^m$, so $V_{1,2} = \pi, V_{1,3}=(4/3)\pi,\ldots$. That makes $\tilde{V}{1,2}=\pi/4\approx 0.7854, \tilde{V}{1,2} = \pi/6 \approx 0.5326$. I'm assuming your numerical methods used randomness and had too few samples for the higher dimensions.

@lngix They didn't use randomness, but yes, there were apparently too few samples. I have attached the code to the question.
